# Why is *&x not the same as x?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

#### Short version:

The following code doesn't compile:

```
CComBSTR temp;
CMenu().GetMenuString(0,   temp, 0);
```

but this does:

```
CComBSTR temp;
CMenu().GetMenuString(0, *&temp, 0);
```

Why?

---

Full code:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
extern CComModule _Module;
#include <atlapp.h>
#include <atlwin.h>
#include <atlctrls.h>

int main() {
    CComBSTR temp;
    CMenu().GetMenuString(0, *&temp, 0);
}
```

`GetMenuString` signature (from `atluser.h`, from WTL):

```
BOOL GetMenuString(UINT nIDItem, BSTR& bstrText, UINT nFlags) const;
```

Comment: What is this I don't even? What's the signature for GetMenuString

Comment: @JesusRamos: Sorry, I forgot to include that. It's part of WTL; I added it at the bottom.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the unary operators `&` and `*` can be overloaded, which I guess `CComBSTR` does.

*** Update: ***

For those who wonder how to get the address of a variable whose type has overloaded `operator&` there is TR1's `std::addressof`, and a Boost implementation of it for C++03 compatibility.

Comment: @kprobst: Wait, `&` can be overloaded?? wtf!! How do you get the address of the variable then?!

Comment: @Mehrdad: With TR1 `std::addressof` or Boost implementation for C++03 compatibility.

Comment: @Mehrdad: You could cast it to another pointer type. But I agree that an overloaded & operator is a minefield of confusion

Comment: You could do something like this (didn't actually check the code):

    template < typename T >
      T * address_of (T & t) {
      return ( reinterpret_cast<T*>(
      & const_cast<char&(
      reinterpret_cast<const volatile char &>( t ) ) ) );
    }

Comment: Wow, I had no idea. Thanks a lot for the answer. +1

Comment: @Mehrdad : `Wait, "&" can be overloaded? wtf!` : Well, of course it can. The "pointer" operators (`&`, `->`, etc.) are overloaded when a class is supposed to behave like a smart pointer, that is, owning some resource, freeing it automatically when not needed anymore (which is the case here, as a CComBSTR wraps a raw BSTR), and enabling the extraction of the raw pointer address, or its dereferencing the familiar way... Conclusion: Without those overloads, there would be no way to have smart pointers mimicking raw pointers' interface.

Comment: @paercebal: I knew `*` and `->` could be overloaded, but overloading `&` seems really weird since (at least at first sight) it means you effectively can't take the address of the variable anymore.

Comment: @Mehrdad : Look at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2001/n1324.html at the section "Getting the address of an object with overloaded operator&". This is quite contrived, but in the other hand, a smart pointer object is not supposed to be used through its own address, only through the address it contains. It's like getting the address of a pointer variable, instead of its value (which is the address of the pointed data), so the cases where you want to retrieve the real address of a smart pointer are limited indeed

Comment: @paercebal: Thanks for the link; the note about `offsetof` is interesting too.

Comment: Wait, so does this mean it's impossible to "correctly" overload `operator&` in C++03 by taking the address of another object (since you don't know the return type)?

Comment: @Mehrdad : `does this mean it's impossible to "correctly" overload operator& in C++03 by taking the address of another object (since you don't know the return type)?` : Can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: @paercebal: `template<typename T> struct MyPtr { shared_ptr<T> p;  ??? operator &() { return &p; } };` What goes in the `???`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4110/discussion-between-paercebal-and-mehrdad)

Comment: @Mehrdad: AFAIK, `shared_ptr` does not overload the `&` operator, so `&p` would return a `shared_ptr<T>*` pointer.  In other smart-pointer types that do overload the `&` operator, a `T**` pointer would be returned instead.

Answer (score 4):

`CComBSTR`  might have overloaded the `operator *` or `operator &` to return a type which matches the parameter type received by `GetMenuString()`

So while `*&x` is same as `x` for built-in data types, it may not be the same for user defined types.

Answer (score 4):

`operator&` on `CComBSTR` is overloaded and returns a `BSTR*`, so dereferencing it gives you the type you need, i.e. a `BSTR`.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not compile, then you should have a meaningful error message?

The function is defined as follows and wants `BSTR&`:

```
BOOL GetMenuString(UINT nIDItem, BSTR& bstrText, UINT nFlags) const
```

`CComBSTR` class does not cast to `BSTR&` itself, but through `& operator` followed by `* operator` it does.